# Cmake can't seem to find needed Qt cmake files even though I've set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: qt, build, cmake

I just recently upgraded to Qt 5.7 and I am trying to build a project that needs to find several packages.  I am on a mac also recently upgraded to el capitan.  I have set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in my .bash_profile and I have checked the environment to verify that it is correct.  When I do a cmake . on the folder my project is in (previously this was how I built) it gives me several errors such as:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:79 (FIND_PACKAGE):
By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
any of the following names:

Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
qt5widgets-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

However I have already verified that the path is correct and that the files do indeed exist.  I have tried several variations of cmake_prefix_path, for instance:

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/mnicholson/Qt/5.7/clang_64/
```

as well as

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/mnicholson/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/cmake/
```

but neither seems to work despite the fact that the cmake files are there.  With older versions of qt setting the path worked, however since upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6 and then to 5.7 I'm baffled...  HELP!! Is this a qt5.7 problem?  El capitan?

Thanks!

Comment: Your path should be `/Users/mnicholson/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets` or `/Users/mnicholson/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5` if you're not just loading the widgets module. The paths you give in example are incomplete

Comment: By the way, you can also try to set Qt5Widgets_DIR (or Qt5_DIR) to avoid pollution of cmake global variables

Comment: So I have to point to every specific folder? I have about 2 dozen of these errors.  I was under the impression (and as I have stated previously this worked in 5.4, and 5.6 with the path as /Users/mnicholson/Qt/5.6/clang_64/) to point to the top folder and that cmake would search the folders under this for what it needed.  So what has changed between 5.6 and 5.7?

Comment: I don't know what has changed. It shouldn't have worked with previous versions. I guess your system was configured in a different way with some system variable pointing to the right place, but I can't tell. You don't have to point to every folder. Just point to Qt5 and specify the modules you need at the root of your project. I propose you answer with an exemple

Comment: I did point to Qt5, and list the modules I need at the root of my project, which is why I'm asking this question.  I rolled back to 5.6.1 for the time being just to get something that will build.

Comment: Syou should update your question to post more of your cmake configuration, including the find_package line. Something like an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can adjust our answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) PATHS option. Something like

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets
    CONFIG
    PATHS /Users/mnicholson/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```